# deleting all pending notifications when user end(terminated) the app at swift

Tags: swift, notifications, swiftui

I'm trying to delete all pending notifications when user quit the app

So I added this code
`func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
       print("This function was executed")
       application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
    }` at `AppDelegate.swift` to delete all pending notifications when user quit the app.

But it didn't work. So I added `print("This function was executed")` and actually quit the app to see whether Xcode prints "This function was executed"

But Xcode doesn't print This "function was executed"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "quit the app".

Comment: @Rudedog I meant terminating the app, (not entering background)

Comment: Terminating an app by swiping it away or hitting stop in Xcode ends the app immediately; iOS does not make any callbacks.`applicationWillTerminate(_:)` is typically only called if iOS decides to evict a background app from memory.

Comment: Thank u for the response, then what function should when I want it to be executed app got terminated by swiping it away?

Comment: You can't. You should re-design your app to do this in some other way.

Comment: Here's some more discussion that might help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223037/how-to-execute-code-when-my-app-terminated-in-background-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code example to remove all pending notification.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```

This code example for unregistering remote notifications.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Comment: thanks u for the response, I added that function at 'AppDelegate.swift' , but sadly that function doesn't get executed. I tried checking with adding a line of printing some string, but Xcode doesn't print that string at all

Comment: My Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504). And I am able to print inside the application will terminate function after the app quite.